# Linux win32 console application development

Tags: linux, pthreads, console-application, win32-process

I am new for developing win32 console application for linux.
I am trying to create console application for linux, but I can not see it on my visual studio. 
Do I need to install any tool for developing this console application?

If yes, then can you please suggest me the name of tool?

Comment: You can have a Linux console application.  You can have a Win32 console application.  You can run a Win32 console application on Linux using WINE.  But there is no such thing as a "Win32 console application for Linux".  **Win32** means "This application is designed to run on Windows"

Comment: Do you know any tools so I can get and I can develope linux based win32 console application?

Comment: For working with pthread do I need to import pthread library in my console application? If yes,  then please suggest me the steps for ?

Comment: @user3360610 What programming language are you planning to use to develop a Pthread related program? Take a look at this given Pthread example written in C programming language on this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads#Example on the same page there is a hint for compiling this C program via GNU Compiler Collection: `gcc pthreads_demo.c -lpthread -o pthreads_demo` After the successful compilation of the program just execute with `./pthreads_demo`

Comment: You're not listening.  There is no such thing as "linux based win32 console application".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a **Windows-based development environment** that can create **Linux executables**.  That is known as ["cross-compiling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), since you are asking a Windows-based compiler to generate code for a Linux system.

Visual Studio supports Linux development via the [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) extension, which you can [download from Microsoft](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e) and install into your Visual Studio.